# Application force A10 Load Balancer to Switch server

Tags: configuration, load-balancing

In a previous network configuration, we used load balancers (Coyote Point) that we could direct in application code to switch the user to a different server (via cookie modification).

Is there some way I can accomplish this with our A10 AX1000 load balancers?